# Single and Range Date picker in react

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I need a React Datepicker which allows to pick both single, multiple and range dates together.

For example, I need to choose 05-03-2022 and 06-03-2022, 10-03-2022 to 12-03-2022, 20-03-2022 to 30-03-2022. I have tried many multi-datepickers but all are allows any one option i mentioned but not all together.

Is there any React Datepicker to achieve this?

Need your valuable help.

Comment: what packages did you already tried?

Comment: @DharmikPatel react-day-picker, react-multi-date-picker and almost all the ones mentioned in this link: https://freefrontend.com/react-js-datepickers/